# Typescript: New instance from object

Tags: typescript, constructor

Is there a way to achieve something like this with Typescript?

```
class Person {
   public name: string;

   constructor(data:any) {
      this = Object.assign(this, data);
   }
}

const p = new Person({name: "Daniel", "age": 30, "gender": "M"});
console.log(p.name) //Daniel
console.log(p.age)  //undefined
console.log(p.gender) //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your aim is. You can forbid such an object literal being passed in to the constructor using `Partial`

```
class Person {
    public name!: string;

    constructor(data:Partial<Person>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}

const p = new Person({name: "Daniel", "age": 30, "gender": "M"}); // error on age and gender
```

This uses typescript's excess property checks to trigger an error those fields (although you should read more on excess property checks as they are only triggered when an object literal is assigned directly to a parameter or variable of a specific type). Long story short you might still end up with extra stuff on `this`.

Another option is to us a custom `assign`  function that only assigns non function fields. Typescript will not let us access type info at runtime so the simplest solution is to use a mapped type that will force us to create an object with the same fields as the original type:

```
type NonFunctionFields<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends Function ? never : P
}[keyof T];

function assignFactory<T>(fields: Record<NonFunctionFields<T>, 1>) {
    return function (target: T, data: Partial<T>) {
        for (let key of Object.keys(fields) as Array<keyof T>) {
            if (key in data) {
                target[key] = data[key]!
            }
        }
    }
}

class Person {
    public name!: string;
    static personAssign = assignFactory<Person>({
        name: 1
    });
    constructor(data: Partial<Person>) {
        Person.personAssign(this, data);
    }
}
const data = { name: "Daniel", "age": 30, "gender": "M" };
const p = new Person(data);
console.log(p.name) //Daniel
console.log(p.age)  //undefined
console.log(p.gender) //undefined
```